# Can I access a list of bluetooth names in IOS 5.1?

Tags: iphone, ios

I did research how to get access bluetooth(BLE) names to display in UITableView. Unfortunately,it is not possible to access built-in settings app as of IOS 5.1.  Does anyone know the way to get the name of bluetooth devices without accessing setting or without using private API?..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The CoreBluetooth framework is used for communication with BLE devices. This should get you started: 
[WWDC Core Bluetooth 101 Video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/#703)

Comment: What I meant is below link. I would want to extract the names of devices discovered in preference. http://cellphones.about.com/od/howtoguides/ss/how_to_connect_bluetooth_headset_iphone_4.htm

Comment: If they are BLE devices you would use the Core Bluetooth framework to search for devices and show the results as a list.

Comment: Martin, I took a look at whole CB framework and run  sample code  but no luck. What I saw are only services and peripherals . Can you tell me a bit more detail?.

Comment: The peripherals have a name on them. You want to display that in your tableview.

Comment: Martin, BluetoothManager can do.. But its private API. Can you show me code snippet?.

Comment: You need to import the CoreBluetooth Framework and start looking around the headers, but iirc the process is just `self.centralManager = [[[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil] autorelease];` then `    [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
` and then you can get a callback through`- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {